# Ansible invoked via Jenkins error "Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

Tags: docker, jenkins, ansible

Looks like this question has been asked before but I have done what other people suggested yet, still get the error.

The user I am running jenkins on is called: **jenkinsuser**

docker is installed with version: **Docker version 20.10.4, build d3cb89e**

jenkinsuser is already in docker group:

```
$> grep docker /etc/group
docker:x:497:jenkinsuser
```

My ansible script looks like this:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:


    - name:
        "get the username running the deploy"
      local_action: command whoami
      register: username_on_the_host


    - debug: var=username_on_the_host

    - name:
        "Download tensorflow/serving image"
      shell: docker pull tensorflow/serving
      become: false
```

and when I invoke it using Jenkins it errors with:

```
TASK [get the username running the deploy] *************************************

changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "username_on_the_host": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": [
            "whoami"
        ], 
        "delta": "0:00:00.014707", 
        "end": "2021-03-05 16:29:34.138218", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2021-03-05 16:29:34.123511", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "jenkinsuser", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "jenkinsuser"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Download tensorflow/serving image] ***************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "docker pull tensorflow/serving", "delta": "0:00:00.120564", "end": "2021-03-05 16:29:50.688169", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-03-05 16:29:50.567605", "stderr": "Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=tensorflow%2Fserving&tag=latest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied", "stderr_lines": ["Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=tensorflow%2Fserving&tag=latest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"], "stdout": "Using default tag: latest", "stdout_lines": ["Using default tag: latest"]}
```

**Am i missing something??
Also, I can not run as root on the jenkins server so i can't run it as root.**

```
$> stat /var/run/docker.sock
  File: ‘/var/run/docker.sock’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 14h/20d Inode: 558480959   Links: 1
Access: (0660/srw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  497/  docker)
Access: 2021-03-05 20:01:04.712848585 +0000
Modify: 2021-03-02 22:00:01.367880977 +0000
Change: 2021-03-02 22:00:01.376880979 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: What happens when you issue the same command directly in a shell on the server as `jenkinsuser` ? Note for later: you should consider using the [`docker_image` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-image-module) rather than using shell.

Comment: It works manually directly in a shell. I think it might be an issue with Jenkins. Do you know how do I find out what user the jenkins build job is running as?

Comment: Did you restart jenkins after adding the user to the docker group ? // you already found out, your playbook is using the local connection so using the localuser jenkins is running as which is `jenkinsuser` as reported by your debug task.

Comment: Yes and just did a restart now too...

Comment: And just to make 100% sure: you have a single master server ? Or do you have a master and slaves ? In the second case, are your sure docker is installed and configured accordingly on every slave your job might run on ?

Comment: One single master jenkins server only. I'm suspecting maybe Jenkins is using a different user when it runs build jobs. I don't know how to find that out..

Comment: Just in case there is any confusion a Jenkins job will always run as the same OS user, so in thise case "jenkinsuser"

Comment: try to stat this socket and see what permissions it has.

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin - I know if I do chmod 666 or 777 this will work but was hoping that adding the jenkinsuser in the docker group should be sufficent, no?

Comment: Replace your `local_action: command whoami` with `shell: whoami` to be in exact same situation of the other shell if you suspect for another user to be used.

Comment: similar issue here.
1) add jenkinsuser to docker group.
2) restart jenkins.
works.
restart is a must.